# trouble learning to model in 2.8

Tags: documentation

I have been watching YouTube videos for 2.8 modeling and they are helpful but they are quick and assume I know stuff I don’t.  I can’t fine some of the menus etc. they quickly access, and I can’t fond the tools the access there.  I need documentation, the lists the menus and how to access them, and the tools they contain and what they do, and how to use them.  It has to be for 2.8 because so much has changed -for example, tracing images are now drag and drop.  I have a very old “For Dummies” book.  I downloaded the “Manual” but that is harder to follow than the program it is supposed to explain.  I am only doing modeling to make 3D stuff to export as .stl files to use with my CarveWright CNC.  I don’t need animation or staging.

Comment: In case you have not seen them I would suggest Blender's own tutorials https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLa1F2ddGya_-UvuAqHAksYnB0qL9yWDO6 and also Grant Abbitt may be a good place for modelling http://gabbitt.co.uk/2.8-beginners-course-1.html This forum is super helpful if you get stuck. Good luck

Comment: Agree with above .. also, Flipped Normals have started making [Blender tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLBX-X8mPyxIqV8Uto03OdvfnGUHCu9Hxz)

Comment: Videos are helpful, but if I get to a point when I need to know how to do a particular thing; I want to be able to go quickly to some reference then back to do it.  If I do it right away, I have a better chance of remembering how next time.  I am 81 and my brain gets full fast. (I started working with computer stuff in 1969 at the beginning of computerized phone switching.)